# no matching distribution found for http.cookiejar

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

That is what I get when I try to pip install http.cookiejar
My Python version is 3.6.2, my pip version is 10.X, my OS is Windows 8.1 64 bit, other modules installed without issues.
I searched my error output on stackoverflow and it seems I first run into this problem
How to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[http.cookiejar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookiejar.html) is a module from stdlib, you don't need to install it.